# Error term when truncating series for $1/\zeta(s)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

Let $s=\sigma+it$, $0\leq \sigma\leq 1$, $|t|\geq 1$, say. Using Euler-Maclaurin, one can easily show that, for $x\geq |t|$,
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} + \frac{x^{1-s}}{s-1} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^\sigma}\right).$$
(In fact, the implied constant is at most $5/6$.)

What about $1/\zeta(s)$? Can one also express
$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} - \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$
as the sum of a leading term plus a much smaller error term,
and, if so, what is the best known bound?

Comment: Are you assuming RH?  Obviously there are problems with zeros.

Comment: Say you are within a zero-free region.

Comment: If you're in a zero-free region you can use the usual bounds for partial sums of Mobius and then partial summation would do the rest.

Comment: I'm not sure that gives me quite white I am asking.

Comment: Assuming RH, for $1/\zeta(s)$ the error should roughly be $1/x^{\sigma-1/2}$ I would think (you can move the contour to be fairly near to the $1/2$-line).

Comment: Section 14.25 of Titchmarsh, treats the case assuming RH. But do not get what you want.

Comment: what size error are you hoping for?  and are you sure the first claim follows from Euler-Maclaurin? (don't you get a $t$ term? i thought you need more to get rid of this)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3316344/8530

Comment: @Lucia What do you mean by "the usual bounds for partial sums of Möbius", though? Does it involve integrals of $1/\zeta(s)$ within the critical strip? The problem is that the critical strip is basically Mordor as far as explicit bounds of $1/\zeta(s)$ are concerned, even under RH (not that I am asking you to give explicit bounds; I can do that). That's why I have asked https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433150/how-to-best-approximate-1-zetas-by-a-finite-sum

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a lousy suggestion, but it's too long for a comment so here goes.  Maybe it's the 
wrong way to think with this problem, but 
my first idea would be to look for an approximate functional equation for the Möbius function, if such a concept makes sense.
\
\ As far as I can see, Theorem 1 (page 47) of "The Approximate Functional Equation for a 
Class of Zeta-functions" Chandrasekharan and Narasimhan "almost" says, if I ignore logs,$$
\begin {eqnarray*}
&&\frac {1}{\zeta (s)}-\sum _{n\leq x}\frac {\mu (n)}{n^s}-\frac {\Delta (1-s)}{\Delta (s)}\sum _{n\leq y}\mu (n)n^{s-1}
\\ &&\hspace {10mm}=\hspace {4mm}\frac {1}{2\pi i }\int _{\mathcal C}\frac {x^{z-s}dz}{\zeta (z)(s-z)}
-x^{-s}\Big (A_{\lambda }^0(x)-S_0(x)\Big )
+\mathcal O\left (x^{-\sigma }+\frac {x^{1/2-\sigma }}{y^{1/2}}\right )
\end {eqnarray*}$$
where according to (46) of that paper essentially
$$A_{\lambda }^0(x)-S_0(x)\ll 1$$
and where $\mathcal C$ is a closed contour containing all the singularities of the integrand so that the integral 
is something like $\ll x^{1-\sigma }/t$ and therefore the LHS above is
$$\begin {eqnarray*}
\ll \frac {x^{1-\sigma }}{t}+x^{-\sigma }+\frac {x^{1/2-\sigma }}{y^{1/2}}
\end {eqnarray*}$$
which is an error quite a bit smaller than the main term for large $t$.  I'm 
thinking of $s$ with around real part $=1$ here just to see what you can expect, but obviously in a zero-free region 
the integral bound above would be better.
\
\ But this theorem isn't applicable to $1/\zeta (s)$ because this function isn't holomorphic on 
a left half-plane :/ Perhaps it's possible to adapt the proof to accomodate for the infinitely many 
singularities of $1/\zeta (s)$.

Comment: The theorem that you quote requires that $\Delta(s)\phi(s)$ has a holomorphic extension to the complement of a compact set, and the extension should tend to zero in every vertical strip (see page 32).

Comment: I know, that's what I referred to at the end of my answer :) my suggestion/hope was that the poles can be maybe accommodated for, since their growth is understood (their horizontal distribution not being relevant for my above error). I don't know.