# Conditional results on average size of Mertens' function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $M(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \mu(n)$ where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. Titchmarsh, in his book on the Riemann zeta function, considers consequences of the hypothesis that
$$\int_{1}^{X} \left( \frac{M(x)}{x}\right)^2 dx \ll \log X,$$
see section 14.29 in the second edition of "The theory of the Riemann zeta-function".

Under the Riemann Hypothesis only (in particular, no assumptions on derivatives of zeta), what upper bounds can be established for
$$\int_{X}^{2X} M(x)^2 dx$$
that do not follow from pointwise bounds on $M(x)$?

Comment: I don't think anything is written down anywhere that does better than what you get from pointwise bounds. I expect you could mine Sound's proof (https://doi.org/10.1515/CRELLE.2009.044) to get something slightly better with a fair amount of work.

Comment: not sure if it helps, but: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348295/error-term-when-truncating-series-for-1-zetas

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thanks Peter. Do you think the situation changes if we assume simplicity of zeros?

Comment: Well, you get the upper bound $X^2\log X$ from the first display, which is better than what the known conditional pointwise upper bound on $M(x)$ gives.

Comment: @GHfromMO Good point. I want to avoid the first equation, however, and see what is the state-of-the-art for the second moment under RH alone. Peter's comment suggests this perhaps was not studied too much and that perhaps Soundararajan's method for proving the pointwise bound $X^2 \exp( (\log X)^2 (\log \log X)^C)$ can be used here to obtain something slightly better.

Comment: Or perhaps $X^2\log X$ is the truth (under RH)! Certainly an interesting question to investigate. BTW in Sound's pointwise upper bound the exponent of $\log X$ inside the exponential is $1/2$ instead of $2$ (of course).