# How to best approximate $1/\zeta(s)$ by a finite sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

I would like to approximate $1/\zeta(s)$ for $s=1+it$ by a finite sum:
$$\frac{1}{\zeta(1+it)} = \sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \eta\left(\frac{n}{x}\right) + 
\epsilon(t)$$
with $\eta$ a function of compact support and $\epsilon(t) \ll 1/t^{2-\epsilon}$, say. The interest would be in making $x$ as small as possible.

If instead of $1/\zeta(1+it)$ we had $\zeta'(1+it)/\zeta(1+it)$ (say), the matter would be fairly straightforward: we can approximate $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ by a sum pretty much as in, say, section 13.2 of Montgomery-Vaughan, but using a zero-free region $1-c/\log t \leq \sigma\leq 1$ instead of RH, and (say) $y=e$. Then $x = \exp((\log t)^2/c)$ suffices to give an error term $\epsilon(t)$ of size roughly $O(1/t)$, whereas $x = \exp((2/c) (\log t)^2)$ would give us an error term of size roughly $O(1/t^2)$, etc.

When it comes to $1/\zeta(1+it)$, however, the only thing I know how to do is to first estimate $(\log \zeta(s))' = \zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ as we just discussed, and then integrate to obtain a bound on $\log \zeta(s)$ for $s$ within the zero-free region, and hence on $1/\zeta(s)$ within the region, worsening quickly close to its left edge. (Alternatively, one can buy a bound like that from the shop, i.e., cite it from Trudgian, 2015.) Then we can write $$\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \eta\left(\frac{n}{x}\right) = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma_0-i\infty}^{\sigma_0+i\infty} \frac{M(z)}{\zeta(s+z)} dz$$
for $\sigma_0$, shift the contour to the left (picking up $A(s)$ as a residue) and end up with a contour integral with $s+z$ going somewhere down the middle of the zero-free region, so that we can give a bound on $1/\zeta(s+z)$ that is not horrible.

This is rather roundabout, and, while it still gives us $x = \exp(C (\log t)^2)$ for some $C$, it is clear that $C$ will be quite a bit larger than $1/c$ or $2/c$ if we want our error terms to be reasonably small.

Is there a more direct way to approximate $1/\zeta(s)$ by a finite sum, preferrably with a smaller $x$?

(We can't proceed just as for $\zeta'(1+it)/\zeta(1 + i t)$ because of the difficulty posed by the residues of $1/\zeta(s)$: we do not know much about them. The residue of $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ at a zero of $\zeta(s)$ is of course equal to the multiplicity of the zero.)